# EQU for non-immediates x86

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am pretty new to assembly, and I have been wondering if there is any operation that could do the same as `EQU` but with registers? E.g.:

```
Boink EQU EAX
```

If there is no such operation, is there any way to equate `Boink` with `EAX` without having to use `RESB, RESD` and so on?

Apologies if this question seems a bit silly to you, and thank you in advance.

I am using NASM.

Comment: You forgot to mention which assembler you use, and what its manual has to say about it ;)

Comment: The answer depends on the assembler and platform you use. Some assemblers support this kind of thing, so it's important to know which one you use.

Comment: I tried that once and found the resulting code extremely confusing. Will never do that again.

Answer (score 3):

The question does seem a bit silly, mainly because your *motivation* is not clear. Why do you want to do this? Is your goal to make the code more readable, essentially giving symbolic (human-readable) names to otherwise inscrutable register names?

If so, you can use [preprocessor macros](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html). Define the macro at the top of your block to introduce the symbolic name, and then make sure that you undefine it at the end of your block to prevent confusion. For example:

```
Max:

    %define value1 edx
    %define value2 ecx
    %define result eax

    sub  value1, value2
    sbb  result, result
    not  result
    and  result, value1
    add  result, value2

    %undef value1
    %undef value2
    %undef result

    ret
```

There *are* cases where this can make the code more readable. The above is arguably one of those cases. It also makes it easier to change the register allocations, which is especially handy when you're playing with (read: benchmarking) code to determine the most optimal allocation strategy.

In MASM, you could do something very similar with the [`TEXTEQU` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/textequ)—*e.g.*,

```
value1  TEXTEQU  <edx>
value2  TEXTEQU  <ecx>
result  TEXTEQU  <eax>
```

But you do have to [be *very* careful with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956996/equ-for-non-immediates-x86#comment76902625_44956996). In real code (at least, real code that has been written to be *efficient*, and if it's not meant to be efficient, why are you writing it in assembly?), you will almost always reuse registers for multiple purposes. This means that your symbolic names quickly become obsolete. Do you keep using the obsolete names throughout the code? Do you alias *multiple* symbolic names for each register, covering all possible uses? Do you continually define, undefine, and redefine new symbolic names for the registers? None of these are good options, and whatever you do, you will just make the code even more confusing.

As such, what you'll generally see assembly programmers do is use comments out to the side of each instruction to explain what is going on with that instruction. Something like:

```
; Uses branchless instructions to find the maximum of two integers.
; Parameters: EDX == value1
;             ECX == value2
; Returns:  Maximum integer value in EAX
; Clobbers: EDX
Max:
    sub  edx, ecx    ; edx <= (edx - ecx)
    sbb  eax, eax    ; eax <= (CF == 1) ? -1        :  0
    not  eax         ; eax <= (CF == 1) ? 0         : -1
    and  eax, edx    ; eax <= (CF == 1) ? 0         : (edx - ecx)
    add  eax, ecx    ; eax <= (CF == 1) ? (0 + ecx) : ((edx - ecx) + ecx)
    ret
```

Comment: Or even use symbolic names in the comments, to help keep track of which high-level variable or expression is currently in which register.